# JPQL @Query - Could not prepare statement exception

Tags: java, jpa, jpql

When I try to execute this JPQL:

```
@Query("SELECT COUNT(v) FROM Vote v JOIN FETCH Restaurant WHERE v.restaurant.id=?1" )
Integer getVoteCountByRestaurantId(int id);
```

I have this exception

```
nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement"
```

I tried to change it to

```
@Query("SELECT COUNT(v.id) FROM Vote v JOIN FETCH Restaurant WHERE v.restaurant.id=?1" )
```

But the exception is the same, what am I doint wrong?

Comment: What underlying [tag:rdbms] are you using?

Comment: @Mureinik  H2 data base

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

`@Query("SELECT COUNT(v.id) FROM Vote v JOIN v.restaurant r WHERE r.id=?1" )`

Comment: Exception mow is:
query specified join fetching, but the owner of the fetched association was not present in the select list
;(

Comment: Could you use just `join` instead of `join fetch`?